# How to install Pages, Numbers and Keynote on Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, pages, keynote, iwork, numbers

I just purchased a used 2006 MacBook Pro with OS X 10.6.8.

I went to the Mac App Store and tried to load Pages, Numbers and Keynote, and it said it could not load them unless I had 10.7.  When I try to upgrade to Mountain Lion, it says my computer does not have the requirements. I can't find Lion—not sure if I could even upgrade to that?

My question I guess: Is there an older version of Pages, Numbers and Keynote that I could get that would work on my machine as-is, without any upgrades?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iWork can still be bought online. Here are [search results for iWork on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=iwork).